# Installing Ubuntu over windows 8.1

Tags: installation

I installed Ubuntu last night on my laptop.
I was using windows 8.1, how can i remove my previous windows and how can i view my C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

if its a dual boot 
Go to **'file system'** and then you will see windows files in the host directory.
If you need to remove the partition with windows 
you have to boot with **live cd** and use **Gparted**.